# How to keep two decimal place correct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In my test, when I use `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:@"%.2f"` method to keep two decimal place.

- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", 9999.999];`
  result is:
  `10000.00`
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", 9999.99];`
  result is:  `9999.99`
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", 9999.9912];`
  result is:  `9999.99`

My requirement is no matter the `float` is whatever, I just want to keep two decimal place, such `9999.999` -> `9999.99`, not the result we saw the first example, how to do with this?

Comment: Use NSNumberFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

1) In `Objective-c`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:99.9999]];
NSLog(@"numberString - %@",numberString);
```

2) In `swift`:

```
let formatter:NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter.init()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.roundingMode = .down
let numberString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber.init(value: 99.9999))
print("numberString - \(numberString!)")
```